# Incorrect Byte Representation in eth_abi

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I am in the process of familiarizing myself with Uniswap v3, albeit with limited success thus far. I am attempting to obtain a quote by invoking the function: quoteExactInput(pathBytes, amountinUint256).call()

For v3, it is required to specify the path in bytes, which I am doing. However, it seems like there might be an issue with the eth_abi module.

Here is the code:

```
    def path_to_encoded_path(self, path):

        fst = encode(["address"], [path[0]])
        snd = encode(["address"], [path[1]])
        thr = encode(["uint24"], [500])

        bytePath = fst + snd + thr

        print("path", path)
        print("fst", fst)
        print("snd", snd)
        print("thr", thr)
        print("bytePath", bytePath)

        return bytePath
```

Here is the output:

```
path ['0x2170ed0880ac9a755fd29b2688956bd959f933f8', '0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955']
fst b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!p\xed\x08\x80\xac\x9au_\xd2\x9b&\x88\x95k\xd9Y\xf93\xf8'
snd b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\xd3\x982o\x99\x05\x9f\xf7uHRF\x99\x90'\xb3\x19yU"
thr b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xf4'
bytePath b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!p\xed\x08\x80\xac\x9au_\xd2\x9b&\x88\x95k\xd9Y\xf93\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\xd3\x982o\x99\x05\x9f\xf7uHRF\x99\x90'\xb3\x19yU\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xf4"
```

*I already tryed:

```
path.append(500)
encode(["address", "address", "uint24"], path)
```

I have not worked extensively with bytes, but the bytePath looks incredibly incorrect with the "!p", "&", etc.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?
Or is there any other module to encode the new uniswapv3 parameters? (since web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters is depricated)

Comment: What is "incredibly incorrect" about "!p"?  Some fraction of the bytes in your bytestrings happen to lie within the range of printable ASCII characters, and the standard representation shows such bytes as the characters, rather than the hexadecimal form.

Comment: There is no issue with `eth_abi` module because it is used hundreds of projects for more than a decade and it works fine. For Uniswap v3 estimation examples [please see here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/uniswap_v3/_autosummary_uniswap_v3/eth_defi.uniswap_v3.price.html#module-eth_defi.uniswap_v3.price). What you are observing is normal Python behavior.